# How to build Android project with Scala sources in IntelliJ IDEA (Community Edition)?

Tags: android, scala, build, intellij-idea, dalvik

I am trying to build an Android project with Scala sources in IntelliJ IDEA (Community Edition). I am using Scala sources from Java files: auto-complete works correctly, but build cannot resolve Scala classes in Java: `cannot find symbol class MyScalaClass`.

(I managed that in Eclipse, but Scala support in Eclipse is poor.)

Any hints or tutorials?

**Update:** I have added Scala module in addition to Android module. Now, build fails during generating `classes.dex` with message:

```
Error: trouble writing output: format == null
```

I found that it is a limitation of Dalvik: [issue 7147](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7147).

How can I strip unused methods/classes in IDEA without using Ant script? (I was using ProGuard in Ant script, but I was unable make IDEA to parse Scala error messages from Ant results.)

Answer (score 1):

The scala/java system requires that you:
- Build scala first, giving the compiler both scala and java files.
- Build the java sources with the compiled scala classes in the path for javac.

The second is probably what you lack. Refer to [how to add directory to classpath in an application run profile in intellij idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/854264/how-to-add-directory-to-classpath-in-an-application-run-profile-in-intellij-idea) to add a classpath to Intellij (I suppose you did it for the android runtime, so you probably already know it).

Comment: Thank you for your hint. I still have troubles:) See my update.

Answer (score 0):

You should use ProGuard to strip down unused classes.

Follow the instructions here (Specifically take a look at the `progaurd-project.txt`:

https://github.com/yareally/android-scala-intellij-no-sbt-plugin