# Play Framework java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory when running tests in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, playframework-2.0

When i generated the play framework example application (play-java) with activator and imported into IntelliJ everything worked fine and I can run up the application.

I can run the tests on the command line and they all work.

However when I try to run them from the IDE i get the following stack:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
    at play.api.Logger$.<init>(Logger.scala:182)
    at play.api.Logger$.<clinit>(Logger.scala)
    at play.api.Play$.<init>(Play.scala:35)
    at play.api.Play$.<clinit>(Play.scala)
    at views.html.play20.welcome$.apply(welcome.template.scala:18)
    at views.html.index$.apply(index.template.scala:33)
    ...
```

I'm pretty sure its something simple, but I'm just moving over to Play/IntelliJ from C# so it's not immediately obvious to me!!

Thanks,

Ben

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the Jar: `slf4j.jar` is't not getting loaded for some reason.

Comment: Yeah its a bit confusing as i used activator to generate the project. It doesn't seem to affect when I run on the command line so I think its an IDE issue. I literally set it up directly before starting the play app so im not sure if it configured incorrectly?

Comment: have you added `slf4j.jar` in your class path of IDE.

Comment: Nope. Do you know how to do this in IntelliJ (Sorry, just moving over to this so it's all a bit new to me)

Comment: Refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16742085/adding-jar-files-to-intellijidea-classpath

Comment: Okay. After doing this through maven, the tests run, but im now getting an the following warnings:  

SLF4J: The requested version 1.6 by your slf4j binding is not compatible with [1.5.5, 1.5.6, 1.5.7, 1.5.8, 1.5.9, 1.5.10]
and
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.

Comment: just configure single self4j binding, it might be next question.