# IntelliJ generated JAR, libraries don't work

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar, executable-jar

I have included libraries using File->Project Structure->Libraries:
[image]

In Artifacts, I made sure to include the library in the output JAR file:
[image]

When I run the program inside IntelliJ, it works fine. However, when I try to run the JAR file it generates, it displays a NoClassDefFoundError:
[image]

So the libraries aren't working. How can I get libraries to work in IntelliJ?

(I have never run into the problem before...)

Comment: Try adding those JARs to the manifest CLASSPATH.

Comment: do you use maven to build your project?

Comment: @GrigoriyDidorenko No

Comment: @duffymo how do I do that? (I have never needed to do that before)

Comment: You're creating an executable JAR, right?  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html

Comment: @duffymo actually I just found out IntelliJ automatically adds JARs specified in Libraries to the classpath http://stackoverflow.com/a/16742141/3830983

Comment: If that were true you wouldn't be asking this question.  IntelliJ does add JARs from libraries into the CLASSPATH when you run inside IntelliJ, but that doesn't fix the problem you have when you run an executable JAR by clicking on it outside the IDE.