# how to use database in java that will work on any computer

Tags: java, mysql, intellij-idea

So i have done a bunch of java programming but this is my first time using a database in an application.

I am using intellij and MySQL

Now i made a simple application to store a random word. The computer i made this application on works perfectly. i can type a word, click save, close the program and the word will reappear the next time i run the program.

However, using this program on another computer i will get the following error

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

How do i make this program work on any other computer

here is some of the code to connect to the database

```
public class ConnectionConfiguration {

public static Connection getConnection() {
    Connection connection = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testDatabase", "root", "qwerty");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return connection;
}
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You need to include mysql's jar files in your classpath every time you execute your program.

Comment: can i get the steps on how to do this. Thanks

Comment: I don't know how to do it on intellij as I don't use it. How did you do it in your intellij?

Comment: I followed the steps here but it doesnt work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16742085/adding-jar-files-to-intellijidea-classpath

Comment: The steps should be correct. You may edit your question, add the steps you have done, and ask what's wrong then.

Comment: How are you executing program on another computer? Using IDEA or just calling java on command line?

Comment: I am using Idea

Answer (score 0):

-Change "localhost" to IP (your computer got DB)
-Extract your jar(mysql) to your jar file(check my last answer in your topic).