# how to include mysql jar files in intelliJ classpath

Tags: java, mysql, intellij-idea

So i am having trouble with adding the mysql jar files in my classpath. 
here is a link to a more detailed version of my problem [how to use database in java that will work on any computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47007759/how-to-use-database-in-java-that-will-work-on-any-computer?noredirect=1#comment80962308_47007759])

So these are the steps i took to add the jar file

1. i went to https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.1.html
   downloaded the mysql-connector-java-5.1.44-bin
2. extracted it and saved it on my desktop
3. went to intellij and did the following 
   file-> project structure -> libraries -> clicked green plus sign and added 
    the jar file heres a picture

[image]

4. Then intellij creates a libraries folder with the mysql-connector-java-5.1.44-bin as an xml heres another pic

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need only add jar(mysql) in libraries when click (+)
You can run in IDE but when you build program to jar file, you must put jar(mysql) to your jar file. 
Go file-> project structure -> artifacts -> right click to jar(mysql) -> extract into output

Comment: @cmptUser did you try this? post your results here