# How to copy artifact .jar and export classpath or it can be added to JAVA_HOME/lib/ext

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar

I'm trying to install https://github.com/awslabs/kinesis-kafka-connector and one of the steps after building a jar is:

```
Copy artifact amazon-kinesis-kafka-connector-0.0.X.jar and export classpath or it can be added to JAVA_HOME/lib/ext
```

I can't find the `ext` folder in my `JAVA_HOME/lib`:

```
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_102.jdk/Contents/Home

$ ls /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_102.jdk/Contents/Home/lib

ant-javafx.jar  dt.jar      javafx-mx.jar   missioncontrol      
packager.jar    tools.jar
ct.sym      ir.idl      jconsole.jar    orb.idl     sa-jdi.jar  visualvm
```

Should I be creating an `ext` folder here and then copying the jar to it or is there any other way to do this? Also, I use intelliJ as my IDE. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add this jar to classpath.

Here is already answer for Idea:
[add jar to Idea classpath of your project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16742141/1974383)

But i recommend you to start using dependency management tools, for ex. maven or gradle. :)