# how can I include a directory in the runtime classpath in Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, dependencies

I would like to have intellij do the equivalent of:

`java -cp "target/skinny.jar:target/lib/*" com.example.ClassName arg2 arg1`

Please show how this can be accomplished in intellij idea.

Comment: Have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16742085/adding-jar-files-to-intellijidea-classpath

Comment: @Divs that looks to be for compiling (javac). I need it to set the classpath for runtime (java).

Answer (score 1):

You can [add a library](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/library.html) for the directory/multiple directories/jars and then include this library into the [module dependencies](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-modules.html#working-with-module-dependencies).

There is no option to provide custom classpath in the Run/Debug configuration at the moment, so it has to be done in the [Project Structure](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/project-structure-dialog.html).

Comment: this looks to be correct, but I could not get it to work for me after trying every permutation of run, compile, test, and provide for the added library.

Comment: @KeyLay could you please zip and share via any file sharing service a small sample project to show the problem?