# ClassNotFoundException on simple Hello World in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ, and get a ClassNotFoundException, even when doing a simple Hello World program.  After googling and looking at [how to add directory to classpath in an application run profile in intellij idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/854264/how-to-add-directory-to-classpath-in-an-application-run-profile-in-intellij-idea), I tried changing my dependencies to the JDK folder (/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_10.jdk), and to no avail.

I have also tried re-installing the JDK and re-installing IntelliJ, both to no avail, and I can run programs in NetBeans without issue.  What's going on?  Is this some strange bug with IntelliJ?

**Code:**

```
public class AppMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

**Error:**

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_17.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Didea.launcher.port=7532 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 13 CE.app/bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_17.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/ant-javafx.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_17.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/dt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_17.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/javafx-doclet.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_17.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/javafx-mx.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_17.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/jconsole.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_17.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/sa-jdi.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_17.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_17.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_17.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/deploy.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_17.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/htmlconverter.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_17.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/javaws.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_17.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jce.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_17.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_17.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfxrt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_17.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/JObjC.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_17.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_17.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_17.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/plugin.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_17.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/resources.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_17.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_17.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_17.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_17.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_17.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_17.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_17.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_10.jdk:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 13 CE.app/lib/idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain AppMain
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: AppMain
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:188)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:113)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Can you provide the full error and the code for the class that is erroring out?

Comment: Can you post the relevant section of code, the full exception message (it usually shows up in your console when you crash), and put a comment next to the line where the exception occurred? Can you also describe exactly how you ran the program, possibly even providing screenshots of where you click?

Comment: Do you see a .class file being created from your compile?

Comment: @mikemil Don't think so, where would that show up?

Comment: @John I ran the program by doing Run from the Run menu, and clicking on Main.

Comment: I just started playing with idea after years of Eclipse.  From what I have seen - i get an 'out' folder under my root folder and then you can drill down from there looking for .class files.

Comment: Did you call your class Main or AppMain? I'm seeing a discrepency in your Exception.

Comment: Ok, can't see an out folder, I will attach a screenshot of what I can see.

Comment: Actually scrap that, because it doesn't seem to be possible to attach images that aren't from the web.

Comment: please check your classpath

Comment: @John I called the class Main, is that where the issue lies?  I'm just baffled as to why such as simple class won't run.

Comment: @Khalil, is there a way of doing that from within IntelliJ?

Comment: `class Main` will never work inside of a file called AppMain.java. Rename your class to AppMain. `class AppMain { blah blah`

Comment: That hasn't made any difference.  I'm still getting the same error, even when I change it to AppMain.  I will update my question.

Comment: I've submitted a support request with JetBrains, hopefully that will shed some light on the situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found out what sorted it.  It was a bug with my import settings, deleting my preferences (i.e. going to ~/Library/Preferences and doing rm -r IdeaIC13) sorted this issue out.  Hopefully that's helpful to anyone else coming across this issue.