# No suitable driver found for jdbc:jtds:sqlserver

Tags: java, jdbc, jboss, jboss7.x, jta

I have explored similar questions, but none of them seem to be the same situation. I have a REST application deployed to the JBOSS 7.1.1 server.  I am using JPA.  Whenever I make a call in the `EntityManager`, I get the following error in the server:

```
15:16:39,024 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1) No suitable driver found for jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://aicdevapp01:1433/MOD_Normal
```

Within the `<datasources>` tag in the **configuration file** of the standalone mode of the JBOSS server, I have the following lines of code:

```
<drivers>
    <driver name="mssql" module="net.sourceforge.jtds">
    <driver-class>net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
    <xa-datasource-class>net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbcx.JtdsDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
     </driver>
 </drivers>
```

Any pointers on where I should be looking at to solve this problem? I can hit the database when I run maven tests, but whenever I deploy to the server I have that problem.

Comment: You need to add it as module in Jboss. check <JBOSS_HOME>/modules
it should be added as module in net\sourceforge.

Answer (score 6):

You have to [download](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jtds/files/) `jtds.jar` and add it to your classpath.

Comment: I will do so. If it works I will accept answer. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I added it to the Windows CLASSPATH environmental variable, but still no luck. I also deployed it together with the ear file and no luck. What else should I attempt?

Comment: Have you put it in the "WEB-INF/lib" of your war?

Answer (score 2):

If using jtds directly i.e.:

```
Driver.getConnection(url, username, password);
```

Then use:

```
Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
```

Else if using a DataSource like for HikariCP use:

```
setDriverClassName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
```

As in:

```
private HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
config.setDriverClassName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
```

Comment: `Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");` this working for me. BTW, I am not a professional java developer. Thnx +10

Answer (score 0):

to add the jtds.jar into the classpath via IDE such as IntelliJ, follow below 
[how to add directory to classpath in an application run profile in intellij idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/854264/how-to-add-directory-to-classpath-in-an-application-run-profile-in-intellij-idea)

more info here:
https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/Structure+of+IntelliJ+IDEA+Project#StructureofIntelliJIDEAProject-HowdoIgetdependenciesandclasspathofamodule%3F

And it is recommended (if you use SBT) to save the un-managed jar in the lib directory of the project. see: http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Library-Dependencies.html

Answer (score 0):

It's also available on [Maven Central](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.jtds/jtds), so in case the project uses Maven, you can just add the following to your `pom.xml` (note that the version may be higher when you read this):

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.jtds/jtds -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
    <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```