# Use JDBC/Mysql Connector in intellij idea

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, intellij-idea

I'm new in Java, and I need to establish a connection to a MySQL server (local), I have add the libraries in Intellij idea but it seems not work, the IDE can't find the class i think... I become crazy I'm searching since two hours... I come from visual studio/c# dev environment and i think that i should miss something...

Here you can have a pic from my IDE and the simple code that I wanted use.
You can also deduce that I have import the jar in my project (mysql-jdbc).

[IDE pic](http://www.noelshack.com/2015-23-1433443595-jdbc.png)

Edit :
here is the code, the comment show where the error appear :

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.*;
import org.*;
import com.mysql.jdbc.Driver;


public class JdbcLogin {
    public String Login;
    public String MotDePasse;
    private boolean Logged = false;

    public void StartBdd(){
        String driverName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        Class.forName(driverName); // here is the ClassNotFoundException

        String serverName = "localhost";
        String mydatabase = "suptodo";
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://" + serverName + "/" + mydatabase;

        String username = "root";
        String password = "azerty";
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
    }
}
```

Comment: Put your code in the question, and format it, don't put pictures of the IDE.

Comment: thank you for your help, i have edit with the post i have think that a pic would be better, so shoud i delete the import line ? its just written on mouseover "unused import statement"... thank again !

Comment: In modern JDBC you are not supposed to have that line (`Class.forName...`) at all. You need to have the jar in the classpath, though.

Comment: You can leave link to picture as additional resource, but it can't be only resource. Also add error message. Anyway why do you need `import org.*;` or `import com.mysql.jdbc.Driver;` at all?

Comment: i wanted to be sure that it was not the source of my problem, i have delete this line now but i still have the same problem :(

Comment: The classpath of intellij is not the same as the classpath of your project/application. Make sure you added the library to the build path of your project!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You have to add 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.40' from maven or add it as java library as shown:

[image]

Answer (score 56):

It's easy to configure. First just open the IntelliJ IDE and follow this simple step:

```
File->Project Structure->Libraries
```

Then click on the plus(+) sign and select `From Maven....`
[image]

After you'll get a search box. There you should put:

[mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.40](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/)

[image]

This will solve the issue.

Comment: This IS all you need to do, for those coming from a C# background don't look for a namespace called mysql - this ADDS classes/drivers etc. into the existing java.sql namespace to add connection functionality for mysql.  You might be better off starting writing some mysql test code and when it fails to connect add the above library.

Answer (score 6):

Solution#1:Drop the mysql-connector-java-version-bin.jar file to your project, right click on it, select "Add as library".

Solution#2:Build and run with command line, for example(Windows)

- javac *yourclassname*
- java -cp".;mysql-connector-java-version-bin.jar" *yourclassname*

Comment: How to directly edit the command line string that IntelliJ uses?

Answer (score 3):

If it says time zone unrecognized  you can add this piece of code to the URL:

```
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost?useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=UTC","USER-NAME","PASSWORD");
```

Don't forget to wrap it with a try-catch.

Answer (score 0):

As an Update this will work with mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.18 as the other version will generate a new problem and won't connect to the database server.