# how to connect mysql

Tags: mysql, intellij-idea

I test database connection using Database Naviagator in IntelliJ. but there is a problem. How can I fix it?
[image: ERROR]

MySQL Server version : 5.1.41-community MySQL Community Server

[build.gradle]

```
runtimeOnly 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.34'
```

[application.properties]

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/example?
                      serverTimezone=UTC&characterEncoding=UTF-8
spring.datasource.username=[my user name]
spring.datasource.password=[my password]
```

**<===== Solution =====>**

1. Upgrade MySQL Server version 8.0.25
2. build.gradle

```
    runtimeOnly 'mysql:mysql-connector-java'
```

3. application.properties

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/example?characterEncoding=UTF-8&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=[username]
spring.datasource.password=[password]
```

4. modify my.ini 
   1) location=> C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0 
   2) open my.ini 
   3) insert into [mysqld] section 
   => default-time-zone='+9:00'
5. restart mysql

Hope it help someone :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use JDBC/Mysql Connector in intellij idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30651830/use-jdbc-mysql-connector-in-intellij-idea)

Comment: The connection in IntelliJs DB Navigator has nothing to do with your configuration in Gradle or Spring's properties. As an aside, MySQL Connector/J 5.1.34 is pretty old. Upgrade to the latest 5.1.x, or better yet to the latest 8.0.x.