# java: package netscape.javascript does not exist, despite having added plugin.jar to the classpath

Tags: javascript, java, intellij-idea, netscape

As per the title, I am trying to build my application, however I get thrown the following error:
`java: package netscape.javascript does not exist`

I am getting this error despite the fact that I have already added plugin.jar from my jre installation to the classpath, I have done this using the steps from [How to add directory to classpath in an application run profile in IntelliJ IDEA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/854264/how-to-add-directory-to-classpath-in-an-application-run-profile-in-intellij-idea) , though it obviously appears to not have worked in my case.

I'm thinking that I will have to do the classpath changes manually (not through IntelliJ), which is something I am *incredibly* inexperienced at, and will thus need some guidance...

Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: You should add the jar to the list of sources in the Project's properties. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051640/correct-way-to-add-external-jars-lib-jar-to-an-intellij-idea-project

Comment: This seems to be the same steps I took in the link I posted, meaning I've already tried this, unless I'm missing something?

Comment: Here's how it looks for me: https://i.imgur.com/q4vOcxK.png