# How to add classpath in Spring Boot when trying to run project locally with IntelliJ

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea, spring-data

Simple Spring boot program to load application.properties from src/main/resource directory:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class PathLearningApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // 1.
        InputStream inputStream = new ClassPathResource("classpath:application.properties").getInputStream(); 

        // 2.
        InputStream inputStream2 = new ClassPathResource("application.properties").getInputStream();

        // 3.
        ResourceLoader resourceLoader = new DefaultResourceLoader();

        Resource resource = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:application.properties");
        resource.getInputStream();

        SpringApplication.run(PathLearningApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

When I tried to run this program locally using Intellij, line number 1. gave me the error:

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [classpath:application.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:199)
    at com.example.PathLearning.PathLearningApplication.main(PathLearningApplication.java:19)
```

While line number 2. (InputStream2) and line number 3. (ResourceLoader works fine).

Here is the classPath set in intellij using stackoverflow

> [How to add directory to classpath in an application run profile in IntelliJ IDEA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/854264/how-to-add-directory-to-classpath-in-an-application-run-profile-in-intellij-idea)

[Classpath set in intellij](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qmdas.png)

So now my questions related to this post are:

1. What is the difference between classpath: prefix and without classpath: prefix in path
2. why line 1 (ClassPathResource) didn't work while line 3 (ResourceLoader) worked in which I have also used classpath prefix.
3. What is the best way of loading the file? Using the classpath prefix or without it, and what is its purpose?

Comment: Spring resource handling - https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html (Sections 6.3 and 6.4 explain Resources and ResourceLoader)

Comment: Can you please tell me why Line 1? ClassPathResource with the "classpath:" prefix is not working.